# Is it possible to configure db-migrate to use a table not named migrations to keep track of migrations?

Tags: node.js, database, dbmigrate

I want to use db-migrate.  But my team wants to use the table name "migrations" for the project.  I do not have authority to change that.

Can I configure db-migrate to keep track of its database migrations in another table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not as hard as I thought it would be.  It is right in the documentation - https://db-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Getting%20Started/installation/.

```
  --migration-table           Set the name of the migration table.
```